# Delay in setTimeout

Tags: jquery, settimeout, setinterval

I want the elements to scale individually one at a time with the delay of 3 seconds.Also when one element is scaled others should be normal.Currently,all the elements are scaled up at once and back to normal after 4 seconds.I have used setTimeout method for the elements and provided the delay of 3 seconds between each elements there but it doesnot seem to be working.To keep the process ongoing,I have used setInterval() also and delay there is 4 seconds.I don't know where I am going wrong.Here is the code snippet to understand better.Any help would be kindly appreciated.

```js
function scale(element){

$(element).toggleClass('found');
}

function autoscale(){
setTimeout(scale('.icons .image:first-child li:first-child'),1000);
setTimeout(scale('.icons .image:first-child li:nth-child(2)'),4000);
setTimeout(scale('.icons .image:first-child li:nth-child(3)'),7000);
setTimeout(scale('.icons .image:last-child li:first-child'),10000);
setTimeout(scale('.icons .image:last-child li:nth-child(2)'),13000);
setTimeout(scale('.icons .image:last-child li:nth-child(3)'),16000);
}
autoscale();
setInterval(autoscale,4000);
```

```css
  .found{
      transform: scale(1.2);
      z-index: 4!important;
  }
  .icons li{
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in;
    list-style-type:none;
  }
   .icons li {
     position: relative;
     line-height: 20px;
     z-index: 2;
     border-radius: 50%;
     padding: 10px;
     width: 80px;
     height: 80px;
     background: linear-gradient(45deg, #a1c4fd,#c2e9fb);
     display: inline-flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;     
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="icons">

       <div class="image">
           <ul>
              <li>
                 <p>A</p>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <p>B</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <p>C</p>
                 </li>  
            </ul>              
         </div>
         <div class="image">
             <ul>
                 <li>
                     <p>D</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <p>E</p>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <p>F</p>
                   </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout()` takes a function as its first argument. You’re calling the function `scale()` and giving its return value to `setTimeout()` instead. So your code is effectively the same as this:

```
var ret = scale('.icons .image:first-child li:first-child');
setTimeout(ret ,1000);
```

So you can see the `scale()` is called immediately.

You need to give it a function, for example

```
setTimeout(function() { scale('.icons .image:first-child li:first-child') }, 1000);
```

This way after the timeout the function is called and then `scale()` is called within.

Comment: Oh,I got it.I thought that as we have to pass a function as an argument so I passed the scale function as an argument to setTimeout.Thank you so much.